# go1.10 build failing with gcc-6 reference

Tags: macos, go

I have go1.10 installed via Homebrew (had the same issue installing the official golang.org package for macOS).

I'm failing to buid a fairly simple go program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/health", healthHandler)

    fmt.Println("Listening for connections")
    http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:5000", nil)
}

func healthHandler(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(writer, "Healthy!")
}
```

`go build` fails with:

```
# crypto/x509
fork/exec /usr/local/bin/gcc-6: no such file or directory
```

I don't have `gcc-6` in my system (I have `gcc-7` from both Xcode and Homebrew).
Oddly, I can build the same code on a different mac (with same overall setup: `go1.10`, no `gcc-6`).

I've tried reinstalling the whole go/gcc combo through Homebrew but nothing seems to work. At this point I just feel lost.

Any ideas?

Comment: check your environment variables

Comment: I don't think gcc is needed to compile Go programs anymore unless you specify it explicitly.  I get somewhat similar error if I do `go build -compiler gccgo` -> `cmd/go: gccgo: exec: "gccgo": executable file not found in $PATH` (I'm on linux).  Is it possible to compile your code  like this? `go build -compiler gc` ?

Comment: @lafolle I thought I had added this comment but JimB's response was correct. I had CC set to gcc-6. Unsetting that variable allowed the code to compile. Just for the record, `go build -compiler gc` fails with the same error (i.e., `gcc-6 not found`) in that environment.